# See shadow from spot in blender

Tags: lighting

I'm new and I have searched but couldn't solve my problem.

I want to see shadow in real time, i have put a spot above a cube. I don't think Blender take it into acount to show me the shadows.

[image]

Comment: Hello, it should work, could you please share your file? https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: You're in object mode, which displays only the 'matcap' which is a pre-made material with predetermined lighting.  Switch to a rendered view to see your lighting and shadows.

Comment: @Allen Simpson he seems to be in Rendered preview mode

Comment: @moonboots I'm also an idiot because I meant to say solid view lol

Comment: Possibly the spotlight has a low strength (10w?) and is being overpowered by the default point light in your scene.  Try 200-1000 watts.

Answer (score 0):

This looks to be because the spotlight simply is not bright enough. The point light in the default Blender startup file is set to an extremely bright 1000 W for some reason, but newly added lights will default to (I think) 1 W. With the spotlight selected, go to the Light properties tab in the Properties editor (hint: bottom right ish, and currently you’re in the Object properties tab), and turn up the wattage. Also, maybe delete the default point light.